# R dplyr - arrange row order dynamically

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(
    company = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "o", "p"),
    EUR = c(1000, 700, 200, 90, 120, 200, 90, 150, 120, 210, 100, 120, 200, 50, 70)
) 

df <- df %>%
    mutate(company = as.character(company)) %>%
    mutate(company = ifelse(row_number() > 10, "others", company)) %>%
    mutate(company = as.factor(company)) %>%
    group_by(company) %>%
    summarise(EUR = sum(EUR, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    arrange(desc(EUR))
df

# A tibble: 11 x 2
   company   EUR
   <fct>   <dbl>
 1 a        1000
 2 b         700
 3 others    540
 4 j         210
 5 c         200
 6 f         200
 7 h         150
 8 e         120
 9 i         120
10 d          90
11 g          90
```

I have this pretty common task. I want to get the top10 company by spendings and summarise the other companies to "other". I know there is an option to manually reorder the rows by changing it to a factor variable and then reordering the levels, but this doesn't work because others can always be in a different place and I have to do this operation for many markets in many different countries. So "Others" should **always be at the last position**, **no matter which line the category is in**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try:

```
df %>%
 arrange(company == "others", desc(EUR))

   company   EUR
   <fct>   <dbl>
 1 a        1000
 2 b         700
 3 j         210
 4 c         200
 5 f         200
 6 h         150
 7 e         120
 8 i         120
 9 d          90
10 g          90
11 others    540
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find out the row number of `"others"` and rearrange using `slice`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice({i <- which.max(company == "others"); c(setdiff(seq_len(n()), i), i)})

#   company   EUR
#   <fct>   <dbl>
# 1 a        1000
# 2 b         700
# 3 j         210
# 4 c         200
# 5 f         200
# 6 h         150
# 7 e         120
# 8 i         120
# 9 d          90
#10 g          90
#11 others    540
```

Same logic in base R would be

```
i <- which.max(df$company == "others")
df[c(setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df)), i), i), ]
```